# Dask iterate over list of columns with map_partitions

Tags: python, csv, dask, parquet, python-polars

I have a large csv (~70GB) and list of dicts like this:

```
[{'Person': ['age', 'sex']},
 {'Work': ['org_name', 'org_phone']}
]
```

The Dataframe looks like this:

```
Person  Work    name    sex org_name            org_phone
36      34254   ali     m   Gualala, Ca         123344
345678  242545  ario    f   Walnut Creek, Ca    123234
534     254534  petr    m   San Francisco, Ca   12323
4532    25252   sam     m   San Francisco       123123
12435   25252   angela  f   Pleasure Point, Ca  123123
36      34254   ali     m   Gualala, Ca         123344
```

This is just a sample data.

I need to iterate over this list of dict and select columns that are in key-value pair (Person, name, sex; Work, org_name, org_phone).

Then I need to exclude duplicates (for example: first and last row are duplicates so I need only one of this rows).

Then I need to add some more info that is stored in other dicts and I can get it by keys like Person, or values like age, sex. And all this I need to save to csv.

In the output csv shouldn't be any duplicates. I cannot come up with better decision than while iterating save everything in parquet files, and the open these parquet files, clean from duplicates and save to single csv.

I have two functions: one that select only keys from dict and iterate over these columns (Person, Work), and another one that iterates over values from dict and work with these columns (name, sex etc.):

```
def create_objects(df):
    for object, props in list_of_dicts.items():
        obj_df = df[[object]].drop_duplicates()
        ...
        obj_df.to_parquet()


def create_values(df):
    for object, props in list_of_dicts.items():
        for prop in props:
            val_df = df[[prop]].drop_duplicates()
            ...
            val_df.to_parquet()
```

My code looks something like this:

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

df = dd.read_csv(filename)

objects = df.map_partitions(create_objects, meta=(df))
values = df.map_partitions(create_values, meta=(df))

with ProgressBar():
    dask.compute(
        objects, values, scheduler='processes'
    )
```

It takes ~2 hours to compute and too much of python memory is stacked. And then I have troubles with opening and cleaning parquet files. Here is my code for this:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.scan_parquet(files).unique()
df.sink_csv(csv_file)
```

I literally puzzled over how to do it better but can't see any other options. But I'm not very familiar with Dask. So maybe professionals here can help me to solve this issue with better performance and less memory leaks. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what "And then I have troubles with opening and cleaning parquet files." means. I see in your dask code that you have drop_duplicates but then you have a polars step to do unique so I don't understand that. Your dict at the top isn't a proper dict so it makes it harder to know what you're trying to do. Should it be like `[{'Person': 36}, {'Work': 34254}, {'org_name':'Gualala, Ca'}] `?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I've edited the list of dicts at the beginning. As of .unique() with polars - I'm not sure that .drop_duplicates() will delete all duplicates across full dataframe. If I understand correctly it will delete duplicates only in this partition...

Comment: Did you have any luck with the duckdb approach?

Comment: @jqurious unfortunately I don't, it takes too much time and then get killed =(